# Changing the directory of files in AmazonS3 uploaded with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

I am using Paperclip + Amazon S3 to manage the uploads of the users. My app is in production now, however I had to change the file path/url from

```
has_attached_file :file, 
:url => "#{ENV['AWS_S3_FOLDER']}/attachments/:basename_:id.:extension", 
:path => "#{ENV['AWS_S3_FOLDER']}/attachments/:basename_:id.:extension"
```

to

```
:url  => "#{ENV['AWS_S3_FOLDER']}/attachments/patient_:patientid/:basename_:id.:extension", 
:path => "#{ENV['AWS_S3_FOLDER']}/attachments/patient_:patientid/:basename_:id.:extension"
```

Now, I can not access the files that is already uploaded on AWS S3, due to the path change. Is there a way to replace the files already uploaded to the right path so I can access them? And another question, what is the difference between :url and :path?

Answer (score 0):

We had a very similar issue. The way we did this was to create a new field in our model, so that we now had two fields that use has_attached_file:

has_attached_file: file

has_attached_file: new_file

in the new_file you define the new correct path.

Then in the migration that handles adding the new_file, put in code to save! each record. 
This puts all the files where they need to go.

Then do one more migration to remove the new_file and change the has_attached_file: file to point to the correct path.

You would then need to clean up S3. In our case it was easy since we changed the root path so we could delete all the old files easily.

We did not define :url, just path, but this was a while back (Rails 3 app).

I can tell you that we now use carrierwave instead of paperclip on all new projects as we find it is better maintained and just works better.

Hope this helps.